# Get the available date range from Availabe date range array and Blocked date range array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 array one of them is having Available date range based on hotel and another array is room based that is having blocked date range. In last step i want to get the only available date range from 1st array.

**Available date range array**

[image]

**Blocked date range array**

[image]

**Expected Result array**

[image]

i tried using get both available array and merge them but failed and also its long process as i have blocked date range stored in my DB.

Comment: Could you please copy and paste the content of the pictures on here? That way it's much easier to read and to compare so that you can be helped better.

Comment: @Doesitmatter sure